# How to pass by reference while building trees?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create an object, lets call it a model, which includes an attribute, the root of a binary tree. I want that model object to have a method which builds a binary tree of a specific depth.

I created such a class, `model`, which uses a tree node class `binary_tree_node`, both shown below:

```py
class binary_tree_node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None

class model:
    def __init__(self, max_depth = 3):
        self.root = None
        self.max_depth = max_depth

    def build_tree(self):
        self.build_tree_recursive_helper(self.root, 0)

    def build_tree_recursive_helper(self, node, current_depth):
        # create the new node
        node = binary_tree_node('data')

        # check base case
        if current_depth >= self.max_depth:
            return

        # make recursive calls
        self.build_tree_recursive_helper(node.left_child, current_depth + 1)
        self.build_tree_recursive_helper(node.right_child, current_depth + 1)
```

I expect to be able to instantiate the model, build the tree, then introspect the tree, like so

```py
m = model()
m.build_tree()
print(m.root.data)
>>> 'data'
```

But instead I get the following upon trying to introspect:

```py
m = model()
m.build_tree()
print(m.root.data)
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-eaa2b3c07e85> in <module>
      1 m = model()
      2 m.build_tree()
----> 3 print(m.root.data)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

This violates my understanding that python passes object references and not values.

How should I modify my `binary_tree_node` and `model classes` to achieve my intended results?

Comment: Read this: [Why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](//stackoverflow.com/q/575196)

Comment: You basically have to rewrite the recursive method so that instead of assigning something to `node` and then recursively populating that node's children, it recursively creates a node + children and returns it, and then you assign that return value to `self.root`.

Comment: Python **does not support call by reference semantics**. The *only* evaluation strategy supported is "call by sharing", better known as call-by-assignment. The problem here is that your `build_tree` method does nothing to the nodes it builds, they are simply discarded.

Comment: Note, python doesn't distinguish between "references and values". There is a common misunderstanding that passing a reference means "call by reference". This is incorrect. C only supports call by value. But you can, of course, pass references (pointers) as arguments. The distinguishing feature in call by reference is that assignments to that parameter in the function are seen in the caller. So imagine we had call by reference in Python along with it's normal strategy and we used `&` to signify such a parameter, `def Foo(&x): x = 42; a = 0; Foo(a); print(a)` would print 42.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why instead don't return the node built and get the reference, something like the next:

```
max_depth = 4

def build_tree_recursive_helper(current_depth): 
    # check base case
    if current_depth >= max_depth:
        return None 

    node = binary_tree_node('data')

    # make recursive calls
    node.left_child = build_tree_recursive_helper(current_depth + 1)
    node.right_child = build_tree_recursive_helper(current_depth + 1)

    return node
```

Note that you have to put the `self` back in your implementation.